# SEO: index linked-to page but do not index URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

In one of my ASP.NET MVC application I'm using an actionlink to switch the language, e.g. `http://example.com/nl/home/switch?lang=en&redirect=/en/home/about`. When the url is pressed, the switch function redirects the user to `/en/home/about` with language `en` (English). The problem is Google is indexing the switch actionlink as if it is the linke-to page. So in this example `/en/home/about` shows up in the Google results as `http://example.com/nl/home/switch?lang=en&redirect=/en/home/about` instead of `http://example.com/en/home/about`. I think `rel="nofollow"` is not an option since the linked-to page will be ignored. Also, in the actionresult I'm using the function `Redirect(..);`, correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the Redirect function sends header 302? Any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't deal well with 302 redirects.  A 302 redirect is a "temporary" redirect.  When you issue a 302, Google may prefer to index the redirect itself because you are saying that the item that it is pointing to may change.   If you changed your redirect code to issue a 301 permanent redirect, I believe that Google would behave as you desire.

Comment: Think you're right, I thought 302 was moved permanently but it's 301. The `Redirect()` function returns 302 so I think I should implement my own function for 301. Doesn't a 301 prevent Google for visiting the link again when it has other parameters?